# Are there two functors between which no natural transformation exists?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, functor, category-theory

I have a `Task`, which is basically a continuation type with an incorporated error case and `Optional`, which represents computations that may not yield a result.

There seems to be a natural transformation from `Option` to `Task` and vice versa:

```
const optTask = tx =>
  match(tx, {
    None: () => Task((res, rej) => rej()),
    Some: ({some}) => Task(res => res(some))
  });

const tOption = tx =>
  tx.task(x => Some(x), _ => None);

optMap(x => x + 1) (tOption(Task(res => res(5)))); // Some(6)
optMap(x => x + 1) (tOption(Task((res, rej) => rej()))); // None

// I can transform back and forth and it still works as expeced:

optMap(x => x + 1) (tOption(optTask(Some(5)))); // Some(6)
optMap(x => x + 1) (tOption(optTask(None))); // None
```

However, `Task` is meant to be used with asynchronous computations, which breaks the natural transformation:

```
const delay = f => ms => x =>
  Task((res, rej) => setTimeout(x => res(f(x)), ms, x));

optMap(x => x + 1) (tOption(delay(x => log(x)) (1000) (5))); // type error
```

I know why it doesn't work. What baffles me is that their seems to be no natural transformation at all, as soon as `Task` is the source of the transformation (and asynchonicity comes into play). But maybe my implementation is just plain wrong.

Here is the complete code:

```js
/***[ Auxiliary ]*************************************************************/

const record = (type, o) =>
  (o[type.name || type] = type.name || type, o);

const union = type => (tag, o) =>
  (o[type] = type, o.tag = tag.name || tag, o);

const match = (tx, o) =>
  o[tx.tag] (tx);

const thisify = f => f({});

const log = x => (console.log(x), x);

const id = x => x;

/***[ Task ]******************************************************************/

const Task = task => record(
  Task,
  thisify(o => {
    o.task = (res, rej) =>
      task(x => {
        o.task = k_ => k_(x);
        return res(x);
      }, rej);
    
    return o;
  }));

// functor

const tMap = f => tx =>
  Task((res, rej) => tx.task(x => res(f(x)), rej));

const delay = f => ms => x =>
  Task((res, rej) => setTimeout(x => res(f(x)), ms, x));

/***[ Option ]****************************************************************/

const Option = union("Option");

const None = Option("None", {});

const Some = some => Option(Some, {some});

// functor

const optMap = f => tx =>
  match(tx, {
    None: _ => None,
    Some: ({some: x}) => Some(f(x))
  });

/***[ Natural transformations ]***********************************************/

const optTask = tx =>
  match(tx, {
    None: () => Task((res, rej) => rej()),
    Some: ({some}) => Task(res => res(some))
  });

const tOption = tx =>
  tx.task(x => Some(x), _ => None);

/***[ Main ]******************************************************************/

const a = optMap(x => x + 1) (tOption(Task(res => res(5))));
const b = optMap(x => x + 1) (tOption(Task((res, rej) => rej())));

const c = optMap(x => x + 1) (tOption(optTask(Some(5))));
const d = optMap(x => x + 1) (tOption(optTask(None)));

console.log(a, b, c, d);

try {
  const e = optMap(x => x + 1) (tOption(delay(x => log(x)) (1000) (5)));
} catch(e) {console.log(e.message)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's plenty of functors with no natural transformations. Consider the identity functor. There can't be a natural transformation from `Option` to it, because there's nothing you can turn `None` into.

Comment: @bob How do you think Constant helps with that?